# Socket.io with Sails.js/Node.js and NGINX on SSL: bad gateway

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, sails.js

I am cross posting this from Serverfault because it seems the Sails team monitors Stackoverflow.

I just started venturing in NGINX and SSL.

Using Ubuntu 16.04.

I am running a Sails server on the standard 1337 port and just set up NGINX with SSL (using letsencrypt). Port 80 is redirected to 443 and upstream goes to Sails.

I also have a Tomcat server listening on 8080 and use NGINX to redirect the same way.

Everything works fine: I can browse both servers on https without special ports on browser.

I have set up socket.io to use websockets protocol only (no polling). This is set on the server and on the browser client.

However, socket.io (sails.io) throws a 502 error no the browser. (polling gave an error too)

Here is my NGINX sites-available for the Sails server:

```
upstream sails {
   server 127.0.0.1:1337 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;
   server_name mysails.server.com;
   return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen 443;
   listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
   server_name mysails.server.com;
   include snippets/ssl-mysails.server.conf;
   include snippers/ssl-params.conf;
   large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;

   location / {
      proxy_pass http://sails/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header Port $server_port;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remot_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_pass_request_headers on;

   }

   location /socket.io/ {
      proxy_pass http://sails/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header Port $server_port;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remot_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_pass_request_headers on;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_buffers 8 32k;
      proxy_buffer_size 64k;

   }   
}
```

The `snippets/ssl-mysails.server.conf` and `snippers/ssl-params.conf` files contain:

```
ssl_certificate /path/to/letsencrypt/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /path/to/letsencrypt/privkey.pem;
```

and

```
# from https://cipherli.st/
# and https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_nginx.html

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_tickets off;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 5s;
# Disable preloading HSTS for now.  You can use the commented out header line that includes
# the "preload" directive if you understand the implications.
#add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
```

Anyone has any clue on what's going on...?

** UPDATE **

I have added a lot of information about logs and behaviours on the Serverfault question

https://serverfault.com/questions/829100/socket-io-with-sails-js-node-js-and-nginx-on-ssl-bad-gateway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is a bad configuration on the NGINX sites-avalable conf file.

```
location /socket.io/ {
      proxy_pass http://sails/;
...
}
```

should be

```
location /socket.io/ {
      proxy_pass http://sails/socket.io/;
...
}
```

Pretty basic stuff: the "location" is not forwarded to the proxy_pass (why would it be, right?) -- So you need to make sure the socket requests are redirected to the exact socket endpoint.